Trusted Signing Integration In Azure Pipelines fails (403 Forbidden, code 0x80004005)
I am receiving a 403 [Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147467259/0x80004005)]when attempting to to a signing on an exe using the TrustedSigning@0 task in Azure Pipelines.
I can confirm the following:

The App Registration has a valid secret
The Identity validation is Completed
The Certificate Profile is Active
The app registration has RBAC roles have "TS Cert Profile Signer" and "TS Identity Verifier" set inside the Trusted Signing Account's IAM
In the yaml, TenantID, ClientID, and ClientSecret match what they should in the App Registration


  ]
}

Submitting digest for signing...
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: D:\ Available 12492.00 MB out of 14333.00 MB, Memory: Used 1989.00 MB out of 7167.00 MB, CPU: Usage 3.97%
Unhandled managed exception
Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)

Headers:
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2024 14:26:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
x-azure-ref: REDACTED
X-Cache: REDACTED
Content-Length: 0

   at Azure.CodeSigning.CertificateProfileRestClient.SignAsync(String codeSigningAccountName, String certificateProfileName, SignRequest body, String xCorrelationId, String clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.CodeSigning.CertificateProfileClient.StartSignAsync(String codeSigningAccountName, String certificateProfileName, SignRequest body, String xCorrelationId, String clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.Core.DigestSigner.SignAsync(UInt32 algorithm, Byte[] digest, SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.Core.DigestSigner.Sign(UInt32 algorithm, Byte[] digest, SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle)
   at AuthenticodeDigestSignExWithFileHandleManaged(_CRYPTOAPI_BLOB* pMetadataBlob, UInt32 digestAlgId, Byte* pbToBeSignedDigest, UInt32 cbToBeSignedDigest, Void* hFile, _CRYPTOAPI_BLOB* pSignedDigest, _CERT_CONTEXT** ppSignerCert, Void* hCertChainStore)

Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147467259/0x80004005)
SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: D:\a\_tasks\TrustedSigning_347b65f8-289b-4164-8663-6dea65cb0cc3\0.3.16\icon.png

SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: D:\a\_tasks\TrustedSigning_347b65f8-289b-4164-8663-6dea65cb0cc3\0.3.16\task.json

SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\TrustedSigning_347b65f8-289b-4164-8663-6dea65cb0cc3\0.3.16\TrustedSigning.ps1.
##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
##[debug]Error record:
##[debug]SignTool failed with exit code 1
##[debug]At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\TrustedSigning\0.3.15\TrustedSigning.psm1:210 char:13
##[debug]+             throw "SignTool failed with exit code $($result)"
##[debug]+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (SignTool failed with exit code 1:String) [], RuntimeException
##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SignTool failed with exit code 1
##[debug] 
##[debug]Script stack trace:
##[debug]at Invoke-TrustedSigning, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\TrustedSigning\0.3.15\TrustedSigning.psm1: line 210
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\TrustedSigning_347b65f8-289b-4164-8663-6dea65cb0cc3\0.3.16\TrustedSigning.ps1: line 226
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]Exception:
##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: SignTool failed with exit code 1
##[error]SignTool failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]SignTool failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
Finishing: Sign hello_world

I am a bit concerned as to why it is trying to sign the task.json and icon.png files...
Here is the pipeline YAML:
stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and Publish Artifact for later signing
    pool: 
      vmImage: windows-latest
    jobs:
     - job: Build_And_Publish
       displayName: Build and Publish HelloWorld
       steps:
         - task: CMake@1
           displayName: CMake prep
           inputs:
             workingDir: build
             cmakeArgs: '..'
        
         - task: CMake@1
           displayName: CMake build
           inputs:
             workingDir: build
             cmakeArgs: '--build .'

         - task: CopyFiles@2
           displayName: Prepare for artifact storage
           inputs:
             contents: 'build\Debug\*'
             targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

         - task: TrustedSigning@0
           displayName: Sign hello_world
           inputs:
             AzureTenantID: 'XXX'
             AzureClientID: 'XXX'
             AzureClientSecret: 'XXX'
             Endpoint: 'https://eus.codesigning.azure.net/'
             CodeSigningAccountName: 'trusted-signing'
             CertificateProfileName: 'LeidosSESPublicTrustTest'
             FilesFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
             FilesFolderFilter: 'exe'
             FilesFolderRecurse: true
             FileDigest: 'SHA256'
             TimestampRfc3161: 'http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com'
             TimestampDigest: 'SHA256'

Trusted Signing Resource JSON:
"id": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/softops/providers/Microsoft.CodeSigning/codesigningaccounts/LeidosSESTrust",
    "name": "LeidosSESTrust",
    "type": "microsoft.codesigning/codesigningaccounts",
    "location": "eastus",
    "tags": {},
    "systemData": {
        "createdBy": "XXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
        "createdByType": "User",
        "createdAt": "2024-05-28T15:22:45.554212Z",
        "lastModifiedBy": "XXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
        "lastModifiedByType": "User",
        "lastModifiedAt": "2024-05-28T15:22:45.554212Z"
    },
    "properties": {
        "sku": {
            "name": "Basic"
        },
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "accountUri": "https://eus.codesigning.azure.net/"
    }
}

App Registration Manifest:
{
    "id": "XXX",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": true,
    "appId": "XXX",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2024-06-26T12:01:43Z",
    "description": null,
    "certification": null,
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "trusted-signing",
    "notes": null,
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2026-06-26T18:31:28.017Z",
            "keyId": "XXX",
            "startDate": "2024-06-26T18:31:28.017Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2024-06-26T18:31:38.0827539Z",
            "hint": "QRa",
            "displayName": "trusted-signing"
        },
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2026-06-26T12:02:59.453Z",
            "keyId": "fba82768-03ad-4d92-a627-4b8aa8a80ed0",
            "startDate": "2024-06-26T12:02:59.453Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2024-06-26T12:03:34.5485852Z",
            "hint": "34y",
            "displayName": "trusted-signing-secret"
        }
    ],Identity Validation Completed
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "XXX",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "eXXX",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}

I have triple checked the following settings, which look correct to me:
Trusted Signing Certificate Profiles
Identity Validation Completed
IAM RBAC Role Assignments
Checked everything relevant found in this answer in another post:

For 403s there can be a few things that can cause this, please check/verify the below:

Check Trusted Signing role.
Check Trusted Signing account name and Trusted Signing Certificate profile name n your metadata.json.
Check dlib and dlib path
Install C++ Redistributables:
Check .Net version, dlib version and Windows SDK
Check if Trusted Signing role is assigned to the identity trying to sign the file.
Check if the corresponding Identity Validation is in "Completed" state.
Verify if you access to the Trusted Signing endpoint from the VM or machine you are trying to sign from?Try executing the action on a different VM or machine. It can be a potential network issue.


Tried everything listed in troubleshooting on the VS Trusted Signing Marketplace page
and I posted a similar question to the VS Trusted Signing Marketplace Q&A.

Hi Brian Baker, I found the issues Issue 1  and issue 2 with the same error message Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147467259/0x80004005) , please check if the solutions in those issues works in your side.

@MiaoTian-MSFT, thank you for taking the time to look at this issue.  I went through both of these links (I had seen the first one previously) and triple-checked each of the solutions within.  I also went through and enabled only one of the Credential type options at a time, just to make sure I was not confused about which type of cred I should be using.  I still have the same issue.

Hi Brian Baker, I noticed that you are using FilesFolderFilter: 'exe' in the task, but the error shows that it is trying to sign the task.json and icon.png files. This is strange. Can you check if the files are correct in the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)? By the way, you can also create an issue here to get more help about the issue.

From the information you pasted, LeidosSESTrust is the account name "xxxxxx/Microsoft.CodeSigning/codesigningaccounts/LeidosSESTrust",
but is different from the account name used in signing.
CodeSigningAccountName: 'trusted-signing'
CertificateProfileName: 'LeidosSESPublicTrustTest'
